# describe command working for one table but not for other table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have 2 tables both from schema A. i am logged in to Oracle SQL Developer with a user A that has access to schema A.
describe table1 -> works fine
describe table2 -> object does not exist
I can see table2 is a valid table from dba_objects,with type TABLE and owner as 'A'
Also i am able to fire select query on table2.

Though i have a different mechanism to checkout table structure in Oracle SQL Developer, was curious to know why describe is working abnormally?
Did i miss something to check for table2?

Comment: Open the log panel. Click on the Statements page... You'll see the SQL we're using to find your object

Comment: Check your table privileges, they may be different.    SELECT * FROM all_tab_privs WHERE table_name IN ('[table1]','[table2]');

Comment: `table2` may have been created with the table name in double-quotes, making the name case sensitive. You can check on that with `select table_name from user_tables where lower(table_name) = 'table2'` (or similar) to see what Oracle thinks the name of the table is.  Although... this should cause issues when you select from the table, too - unless you are careful when you do *that*, but not when you use `describe`.